# select columns that exist in in table1 and not in table2 where table1 and table2 differ in columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry I don't know how to express my question correctly in the title, and I hope I can explain it better here:

I want to select column1 and column2 from table1 which don't exist in table2,
but  the proplem is table2 has only the column1 but not column2 which give me an error.

here is my code:

```
select column1, column2  from table1 except select column1, column2 from table2
```

I also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
select column1, column2  from table1 except select column1 from table2
```

Comment: This is a pretty long way from valid SQL.  Can you show us what your tables look like? And a bit of sample data to show us what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  What is your scenario?

Comment: I will add the scenario above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick answer based on the information you've given:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column1 NOT IN (
    SELECT column1
    FROM table2
)
```